# Which Moby Dick appears on Khan's bookshelf?

Tags: star-trek, object-identification, the-wrath-of-khan

Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157061/), I'm curious as to which exact printing of *Moby Dick* (edition, year, publisher) appears on Khan's bookshelf in *The Wrath of Khan*:

[image]

**Does anyone know?**

Comment: Interesting how other books on Khan's shelf are also relevant to the story.

Comment: Any idea what the two books are to the left of King Lear?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good possibility that it is this edition. Signet Classic logo on the spine, green border visible on the cover, and typeface is similar

[image]

[image]

[image]

(found here) - http://www.ebay.com/itm/1961-Moby-Dick-by-Herman-Melville-CT47-signet-classic-/162110063894

Comment: It can't be *exactly* that printing, because the words "Herman" and "Melville" are placed one after the other along the spine, rather than on top of each other as in the OP's photo. Still, good find, and you've certainly got the publisher right!

Comment: good catch on Melville's name on the spine - it's definitely an edition of this though imo. I'll see what I can dig up to get a better match on the spine

Comment: I'm impressed!  I'll give you more time to see if you can get that better match on the spine.  (It could be the same edition but a slight regional variation in the formatting.)

Comment: @Praxis - Could be the CT47 edition then, but I can't find a good image of the spine for that one. "CT47" being on the cover which is not on this cover, which in every other way seems to be the same design

Comment: Here's a [picture](http://www.mobydickbigread.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Chapter-37-richard-baker-300.jpg) of a different printing, showing the book spine.

Comment: The book from the movie does have the Signet logo, but the cover appears to have a white border, not a green border.

Comment: @JoeL. That could just be fading from age.

Comment: @NKCampbell : I'm going to go ahead and accept this!  If something else comes up in the future, I might revisit this, but somehow I suspect this is the closest we'll get.  Thanks again for the great work.