# Why does Khan have two copies of "Paradise Lost"?

Tags: star-trek, the-wrath-of-khan

Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157071/which-moby-dick-appears-on-khans-bookshelf) (which was inspired by [this other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157061/what-is-the-significance-of-chekov-s-finding-moby-dick-on-khan-s-bookshelf-in-th)).

In his bookshelf, Khan has [two copies of John Milton's *Paradise Lost*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Paradise_Lost). One of them looks newer and thinner, and it also contains *Paradise Regained*.

Is there a significance in the fact he has two copies? Or is it just a mistake by the prop department? Have the filmmakers discussed this?

Note, I'm not asking why *someone* like you or me may have two copies of a book. I'm asking if there are canonical in-universe or out-of-universe reasons for *Khan* to have those two copies of Paradise Lost (e.g. he loves it more than, say, Moby Dick; the producers wanted to stress he's more Satan than Ahab; the *Regained* copy belonged to his wife and when she died he *lost* the possibility of *redemption*; two people from the prop department brought their own copy of the book and they decided to use both; the font of the main book title looked not enough visible and the prop department had to add a second copy so the viewers don't miss it; etc).

If no canonical reason exist, the best speculation "within the spirit of canon" will be awarded the green mark.

Comment: In case he wants to read it more than once?

Comment: I can only speculate, but it would be in keeping with a bibliophile's tendency to acquire multiple copes of the same book, and original editions wherever possible.  I'd suggest the larger book is an original printing (or very nearly), and the other is the paperback version for casual reading.

Comment: @Tim you say you "can only speculate", but it seems to me a very good speculation!

Comment: ...In case one of them gets lost?

Comment: One may be a "shelf" copy while the other is a "read" copy.

Comment: Huh? I have three copies of *The Reefs of Earth.* So what??

Comment: @user14111: and I have two copies of some books too, but you have your reasons, I may have my reasons, - and I'd like to know Khan's reasons :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some copies of works such as this are more thoroughly annotated. I, for example, have several different copies of Romeo & Juliet and the Complete Works of William Shakespeare, mainly because the annotations are different. One copy may focus on word usage of the day, the other might include more references to other contemporaneous work of the day or might have heavy references to Shakespeare's inspiration and influences regarding a particular story-line or bit of poetics.

And, if I really love a book, I want multiple copies to give away.

Reasons why:
1) The look.

2) People know you like a classical author and get you more copies.

3) Different information in different editions.

4) So that you can spread the gospel and be okay about lending or giving away copies because you have multiple.

5) A battered copy to write your own notations in.

6) This is the reason I see for Khan here: **collections from an author often include something you already own, but you go ahead and buy it. It's actually difficult to find Paradise Regained on its own. The same is often true of less popular Shakespearean plays, which will be found packaged with more popular plays such as Romeo & Juliet, or Twelfth Night, but aren't found as often on their own.**

Comment: After a month, I must accept the fact that there is not a canonical reason. So, as I promised, I accept this answer even if it is speculation, because it is a good speculation. Thank you Erin!

Answer (score 1):

Khan also once spoke of "his beloved wife." Perhaps they enjoyed reading the book together.

Comment: Perhaps. This answer could benefit from some sources, though.